# how do i edit the username and password prompt window for my protected virtual path?

Tags: virtual-directory, restrictions, password-protected, prompt

I am using abyss web server X2 to create this username and password prompt window for my protected virtual path. 
I would like to edit this prompt window or pop up with my custom text for the visitors.
Thank for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clearly stated in [Abyss Web Server User's Guide](https://www.google.fi/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://aprelium.com/data/doc/2/abyssws-win-doc.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjKv_7p46rTAhXSIlAKHY1MDMoQFggsMAE&usg=AFQjCNHDfUjImyM7S7QUOKnHUgJI1LG18Q&sig2=PCaisCpXHR4Uoakjg8MTOw), but based on the fields used in chapter *Access Control* (pages 48-50) it seems the feature is an implementation of [HTTP basic authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-11.1). As this is a feature of HTTP protocol, every browser generates its own prompt for username and password and there's no way to customize it.

However, you can put this short message to your users in the *realm* field. Its content will be shown to the user on the prompt for username and password.

> • **Realm**: A short description of the path’s contents. It is prompted to
> users by the browser when it asks them for credentials.